# python variable parameter performance differnt in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, variables, parameters

```
def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args) :
        print "call func name: %s()" % func.__name__
        return func(args)
    return wrapper

@log
def func_test(*args):
    print 'today'
    for x in args:
        print x

def calc_sum(*args):
    ax = 0
    for n in args:
        print n
        ax = ax + n
    return ax

func_test(1,2,3,4)  
calc_sum(1,2,3,4)
```

i expect the result is

```
call func name: func_test()
today
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

but the output is

```
call func name: func_test()
today
(1, 2, 3, 4)
1
2
3
4
```

both method i give variable parameters , i want user "@log" to print parameters 
int the method "func_test", the parmeters changes.
could some one tell me what's going on?
thanks!